# Is the Local Average of a Continuous Multivariable Function Differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity, leibniz-integral-rule

Suppose we have a continuous $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. It is an immediate corollary of the Leibniz integral rule that $f^*:x\mapsto\int_{x-\frac{1}{2}}^{x+\frac{1}{2}}f(t)\ dt$, the "local" average of $f$ on the interval of length one centred at $x$, is a continuously differentiable function in $x$. I was wondering how far we can get extending this result into higher dimensions. Specifically, let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ be continuous. For $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, let $B_r(x)$ be the closed ball of radius $r$ around $x$. Then, is the function $f^*:x\to\int_{B_{\frac{1}{2}}(x)}f(t)\ dt$, where the integral is the standard integral for vector-valued functions, a continuously differentiable function? Could we say, integrate over a square instead of a circle?

Comment: The real answer goes into Sobolev spaces and how these interact with respect to the operation called "convolution". All the averaging processes written above are convolutions with respect to certain fixed functions (all indicator functions, incidentally), and it turns out that the "regularity" of this indicator function determines exactly the regularity of the convolution. In your case, I believe that the integration over a square, circle etc. *do not* fall into a good enough regularity class that the averages are continuously differentiable.

Comment: Pardon me : they do fall into a good enough class, but I think I'll struggle to bring this down to an acceptable level of simplicity, so I'll bail out and let someone more informed write an answer.